# Is it right to add possessive verb?

Tags: grammar, sentence, possessives

> Every illness is a story, and Annie Page’s began with the kinds of small, unexceptional details that mean nothing until seen in hindsight.

I will like to check if there is any grammatical error in this phrase "Annie Page's began with ...". The word began(verb) after apostrophe seems to be wrong. Can anyone help out?

Comment: The grammar is OK, but there might be an ambiguity as to whether "Annie Page's" refers to her illness or to her story.

Comment: Given the context, "Annie Page's" is presumably qualifying "story".

Comment: Annie Page's(noun) began(verb) with. Hmm even if Annie Page's is a story or illness, or more generally a noun, why is there an apostrophe? Isn't the grammatically incorrect? @AndreasBlass

Comment: @HotLicks too, Hmm even if Annie Page's is a story or illness, or more generally a noun, why is there an apostrophe? Isn't the grammatically incorrect?

Comment: Certainly it's correct. The sense is  _Annie Page's story (or illness) began..._

Comment: @kitcat - Because the second "story" is elided.  "Every illness is a story, and Annie Page’s [story] began with ..."

Comment: I understand the theme of "Every illness is a story," as being  "illness". It tells us what all illnesses are. It seems reasonable that "Anne Page's" thus refers to "illness".